# Not sending email to desired address

Tags: php, mysql, email

Hi can someone have a look at this code, this was working yesterday and thee emailw as being sent to the correct address, now it will not work but the success message is still being displayed. Any ideas?

```
mysql_select_db("lr", $con);

require 'mail/class.simple_mail.php';
$mailer = new SimpleMail();

$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'];
$time = $_REQUEST['time'];
$date = $_REQUEST['date'];
$place = $_REQUEST['place'];


$message = "<strong>This is an email from the bride to you the bridesmaids, here is the information on the next dress fitting<br /><br />Date:".$date." <br /> Time:".$time."<br />Place: ".$place." <br /> Any other comments:<br />".$comments." </strong>";



$send   = $mailer->setTo('edonaghy--@hotmail.co.uk', 'Your Email')
                 ->setSubject('Dress Fitting')
                 ->setFrom('donaghy-e5@email.ulster.ac.uk', 'WeddingsNI-A-Z')
                 ->addMailHeader('Reply-To', 'donaghy-e5@email.ulster.ac.uk', 'Wedding Ni A-Z')
                 ->addMailHeader('Cc', 'donaghy-e5@email.ulster.ac.uk', 'WeddingNIA-Z')
                 ->addGenericHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"')
                 ->setMessage($message)
                 ->setWrap(100)
                 ->send();
echo ($send) ? 'Your Email has been sent to your bridesmaids' : 'Could not send email';
```

Comment: *"this was working yesterday"* --- So, what changed since? If it worked, where's your backup copy that did work? Check your other/old questions, seems like you have similar code there that you could revert to.

Comment: "It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination."

Comment: What does it say in the maillog?  And: consider removing mysql tag and adding mail tag on this Q.